# Multi select dropdown on change (select/un-select), update array

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, drop-down-menu

I want to make a multi select dropdown in Angular with the selected values are shown as chip tags. On clicking the 'X' sign, the value should be unselected and chip tag should be removed.

```
<searchable-dropdown
        class="someClass"
        [items]="myObject.element.options">
</searchable-dropdown>
```

I have declared my object as

```
  myObject: any =  {
    key:'myidentifier',
    element: {
      options: [
        {title: 'option1'},
        {title: 'option2'}
      ]
    }
  };
```

I was thinking to use this way to achieve my functionality

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let optn of SomeArray">
      <span >{{optn}}</span>
      <span class="close-tag"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want re render my li according to change in multi-select dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ng-select](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/data-sources). And follow [this example](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/tree/master/src/demo/app/examples/multi-checkbox-example) to create a custom multiselect dropdown with an option to search.

Comment: How can I re-render my li so that it is updated everytime on dropdown select/unselect.